# Is it possible to choose between various X.Org configurations and rc scripts via GRUB?

Tags: linux, boot, grub

I have AMD/Intel hybrid graphics. I have been using only Intel GPU when AMD Proprietary crashed X.Org. Now i'm having installed Catalyst and i've recognized higher power usage.

In both AMD/Intel and Intel only solutions i have blacklisted `radeon` module.

For Intel only solution my `rc.local` looks:

```
modprobe radeon
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

And for AMD/Intel hybrid solution i have different `xorg.conf` configured via `aticonfig`.

So i'd like to have `rc_intel.local`,`rc_amd.local`, `xorg_intel.conf`, `xorg_amd.conf` and switch between them via different grub menu entries.

Is it possible?

*Sorry for my english*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, parameters passed to the kernel command line (editable in your bootloader's configs) end up on /proc/cmdline.  Just parse it for your keywords.

```
case "$(< /proc/cmdline)" in
  *keyword*)do something;;
  *another*)do another;;
esac
```